# Creating separate input and output modules

Tags: java, methods

I'm making a program where the user inputs values for diameter, length, width, base, height. Those values are put through some calculations for area. Area is calculated and spat back out to the user in various different units. After making it I separated it into several submodules (methods in Java).

However, when I separate my input and output modules, it won't compile, because the variables are initialized within the input method.

If I try to define the variables within the method (obviously doesn't work) because I've already defined and initialized the variables within the input method(s).

How can I enable my output method to use the variables initialized by the user in the input methods.

The idea is meant to be that my main is just:

```
Main 
{
    inputInteger();
    inputReal();
    outputCRT(); //CRT = Circle Rectangle Triangle
}
```

I thought you passed variables between methods like:

```
outputCRT(int diameter, double length...etc)
{
  all my output
}
```

But (I'm pretty sure) this means that when I call it in my main I'd have to give it values:

```
Main 
{
    outputCRT(8, 32.43...etc);
}
```

But that defeats the whole purpose of users inputting their own values in using the scanner. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point you should gather the input in some way in your "input modules" (e.g. `inputInteger()`), then use the inputs in the "output modules" (e.g. `outputCRT(...)`).

You can achieve this by returning the results of your input methods and using them as arguments for your output methods. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int diameter = inputInteger();
    double length = inputReal();
    ...
    outputCRT(diameter, length, ...);
}

static int inputInteger() {
    int value = read input in some way;
    return value;
}

static double inputReal() {
    double value = read input in some way;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I am confused by your answer.... why did you make the function return values, while not using them (why not void both functions)? Also, this is a school project, never give the answer, rather point the user how to create the answer himself

Comment: @Bonatti edited the question. Of course this is not the solution, only a way he could follow.

Comment: The code doesn't really help much becayse it doesn't really apply to how I have my program set up. However, setting up the variable to be equal to a method is new to me (as seen in like 2 and 3 of your code), might be able to play around with that to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school projetct, it is likely that your teacher is giving you incremental information...

It appears that your teacher want you to use global variables in the class, and then make you use them. This way, the `inputInteger` function would set a group of variables, then `inputReal` would set another group and finaly `outputCRT` would output the result.

Comment: I'll have a look into setting global variables, don't quite understand how to pass variables in and out of methods yet though.

Also the project first started with like everything happening in the main, then the calculating area parts got made into seperate methods, then the main was split into circleStuff, rectangleStuff and triangleStuff. They each contained initialising the variables (input), then passed that to the calc module, then read out the results (output). It's just the next part of the project is to spread out the input and output as described and it's proving a tad difficult.

Comment: So far, it appears you are using "procedural orientation", something that java will do, but it is not its strength. Java uses "Object Orientation (OO)", so, consider "A Circle", that has an attribute "diameter", and a method "getCircunference", that returns a number.... you are learning the language in parts, and for this reason, must understand what/why you are doing it. When you allocate `int diameter`, you are reserving a name and a memory region. You can now change the value in that space, and read the state of that region.... the overall need of the program, remains the same.